# Dagger2: Using factory methods in place of public constructors

Tags: java, dependency-injection, factory, dagger-2

I am trying to use public factory methods in place of public constructors with Dagger2. But  think I am missing some connection in using Dagger2.

When I use public constructors, my example interfaces / classes are as follows:

```
interface InterfaceA {
    void foo();
}

class A implements InterfaceA {

    @Inject public A() {}

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}

interface InterfaceB {
    void bar();
}

class B implements InterfaceB {

    private final InterfaceA depA;

    @Inject public B(InterfaceA depInstance) {
        depA = depInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar");
        depA.foo();
    }
}

@Module class MyModule {

    @Provides InterfaceA provideA(final Provider<A> provider) {
        return A.create(provider);
    }

    @Provides InterfaceB provideB(B bInstance) {
        return bInstance;
    }
}

@Component(modules=MyModule.class)
interface MyComponent {
    InterfaceA provideInterfaceA();
    InterfaceB provideInterfaceB();
}
```

Usage for the above:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyComponent comp = DaggerMyComponent.create();
        InterfaceA a = comp.provideInterfaceA();
        a.foo();
        InterfaceB b = comp.provideInterfaceB();
        b.bar();
    }
}
```

Now, If I rewrite the classes A and B as follows:

```
class A implements InterfaceA {

    public static A create() {
        return new A();
    }

    private A() {}

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}

class B implements InterfaceB {

    public static B create(InterfaceA depA) {
        return new B(depA);
    }

    private final InterfaceA depA;

    private B(InterfaceA depInstance) {
        depA = depInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar");
        depA.foo();
    }
}
```

I am able to re-write MyModule class as:

```
@Module class MyModule {

    @Provides InterfaceA provideA() {
        return A.create();
    }

    @Provides InterfaceB provideB() {
        return B.create(provideA());
    }
}
```

But this does not use much of the Dagger2 framework. 
Looks like I am not writing my classes to use the Inject and Provides annotations correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure you are intentionally using unscoped provider methods and unscoped components; every inject call creates a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually pretty close, you're making minor mistakes though. You should provide the instance to the provider method using method parameter, otherwise you'd create multiple instances in case of a scoped provider. And you can use `void inject(Something something);` if you want.

```
@Module class MyModule {

    @Provides InterfaceA provideA() {
        return A.create();
    }

    @Provides InterfaceB provideB(Interface A interfaceA) {
        return B.create(interfaceA);
    }
}


@Component(modules=MyModule.class)
interface MyComponent {
    InterfaceA provideInterfaceA();
    InterfaceB provideInterfaceB();

    void inject(Test test);
}

public class Test {
    @Inject
    InterfaceA a;

    @Inject
    InterfaceB b;



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyComponent comp = DaggerMyComponent.create();
        comp.inject(this);
        a.foo();
        b.bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are intentionally using unscoped provider methods and unscoped components; every inject call creates a new instance. To provide a scope, put a `@Singleton` on your component, and on the `@Provides` methods that you want to be scoped.